# Best way to have an 'complex' operation function with two C++ vectors as arguments

Tags: c++

To make things simple, may I ask whats the best way to write the following code in C++ with the following Python code

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1,2,3,...])
Y = np.array([10,11,12,...])

def funct(X,Y):
  return 0.5 * X + 0.5 * 3 * Y
```

Alternatively, to explain without Python, is there a way to:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> Z {};
std::vector<double> X {1,2,3,4};
std::vector<double> Y {5,6,7,8};

Z = 0.5 * X + 0.5 * 3 * Y; // something like this
```

Comment: Create another class that contains a `std::vector<double>` and supports the required operations.   Yes, that means you will need to implement the logic, but them you can reuse the implementation.    `std::vector` does not, in itself, support math operations that (say) contribute to calculating a linear combination of vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps `valarray` is what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main() {
    std::valarray<double> Z {};
    std::valarray<double> X {1,2,3,4};
    std::valarray<double> Y {5,6,7,8};
    Z = 0.5 * X + 0.5 * 3 * Y;

    for(auto v : Z) std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
8
10
12
14
```

Note from [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray): "*The behaviour is undefined when the two arguments are valarrays with different sizes.*"

Comment: Note that element-wise operations with two `valarrays` with different sizes have Undefined Behaviour

Comment: @alterigel Yeah, but that's not the case here, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo right, it's not the case here, but it would be nice to add a small warning, just in case. It's likely that someone coming from Python doesn't quite expect that.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Ok, added a note!

Comment: Great to see a suggestion to use valarray! I rarely see it being used. It's really old, but how mature is it? I mean, is it properly supported by optimizers? Last time I tried to use a vallarray in ms vs2019, it turned out it was actually broken in the ms stl (its fixed now).

Comment: @JHBonarius The first note on `valarray` is interesting:. It says (among other things):  "_Some C++ standard library implementations use expression templates to implement efficient operations on `std::valarray` (e.g. GNU libstdc++ and LLVM libc++). Only rarely are valarrays optimized any further, as in e.g. Intel Integrated Performance Primitives_"

Comment: Interesting. [I tried to bench it](https://quick-bench.com/q/4sIue6DvtBkvsTt1IRf9uNxqdIg) but I cannot get valarray to test properly. (Or it's insanely fast...probably not)

Comment: @JHBonarius Oh my ... That's impressive :-) Seriously: That _is_ interesting. I wasn't able to bench it properly either.

Comment: OK, found my mistake. Wrong constructor for std::valarray. Anyhow, [it would seen that valarray is 3.3x faster then vector/algo](https://quick-bench.com/q/G3X-qT_QMz--r8aGrTbMA6LlmKM) . But as valarray uses expression trees, I'm not sure thats actually the case. [I did a second bench where I accumulate the output](https://quick-bench.com/q/GFMW0tUmkmThxv3s3VbTgITkpNk), which gives a different result (~1.5x) but the accumulate is also in the bench loop, so the bench is not isolated. Still valarray seems faster! noice!

Answer (score 3):

`std::transform` is the STL algorithm that does what you wnat.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void f(){
    std::vector<double> X {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<double> Y {5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<double> Z(X.size());
    std::transform(X.begin(), X.end(), Y.begin(), Z.begin(),
                   [](double x, double y) noexcept { return 0.5 * x + 0.5 * 3 * y; });
}
```

Please note that the target `vector` needs either to have enough elements before `std::transform` is being called (see code above) or you need an iterator that appends to `vector` like in

```
std::transform(X.begin(), X.end(), Y.begin(), std::back_inserter(Z),
               [](double x, double y) noexcept { return 0.5 * x + 0.5 * 3 * y; });
```

If you don't want all the reallocations that `back_inserter` triggers you could create an empty `Z` first, then reserve enough space in `Z` and then call `transform` using the `back_inserter`.

```
std::vector<double> Z;
Z.reserve(X.size());
std::transform(X.begin(), X.end(), Y.begin(), std::back_inserter(Z),
               [](double x, double y) noexcept { return 0.5 * x + 0.5 * 3 * y; });
```

Please note that `transform` assumes that for each element in the first range (`X.begin()` up to `X.end()`) there must be a corresponding element in the second range (starting at `Y.begin()`). You might need to check that beforehand and possibly only work on sub ranges of `X` and `Y`.

There is also an overload that takes an `ExecutionPolicy` in case you want the transformation to be parallelized.

Comment: You want [`std::back_inserter(Z)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), not `Z.begin()`.

Comment: @Brian I know, I am just in the process of testing and editing :).

Answer (score 2):

Boost has a [numeric vector class](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.html):

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/assignment.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>

int main() {
  using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
  vector<double> x(3);
  x <<= 1, 2, 3;
  vector<double> y(3);
  y <<= 10, 11, 12;

  vector<double> z = 0.5 * x + 0.5 * 3 * y;

  std::cout << z << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
[3](15.5,17.5,19.5)
```

[<kbd>Live</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wvo68a)